# Can I bury a bare ground connecting rod?

Tags: electrical, grounding, electrical-panel

We just ripped out an old rotting deck at our house, this exposed the wire that connects the electrical panel to the grounding rods.  There is a PVC pipe encasing the wire from the panel to ground level.  Can I just dig a trench and burry this wire?  If so does it need to be a particular depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bury it, the depth is not critical, so long as the wire is protected from physical damage.  But why isn't the ground rod next to where the pvc pipe comes down?  That would be preferable to having this long roving wire.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is set up this way.  The house is 99 years old and was wired after being built. The panel has been updated since then but I'm not sure when the ground was added.  It must have been after the deck was built, because the ground ran around a some of the support beams.  We're just finding all kinds of surprises!  Thanks for the answer